# Determinant equal to zero : elements are angles

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be internal angles of an arbitrary triangle.

I want to show that $$\det \begin{pmatrix}\cos \beta & \cos \alpha&-1 \\ \cos\gamma & -1 & \cos\alpha \\ -1 & \cos\gamma & \cos\beta\end{pmatrix}=0$$

We have the following: 
\begin{align*}&\det \begin{pmatrix}\cos \beta & \cos \alpha&-1 \\ \cos\gamma & -1 & \cos\alpha \\ -1 & \cos\gamma & \cos\beta\end{pmatrix}=\cos \beta \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix}  -1 & \cos\alpha \\  \cos\gamma & \cos\beta\end{pmatrix}-\cos \alpha \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} \cos\gamma & \cos\alpha \\ -1 & \cos\beta\end{pmatrix}+(-1)\cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} \cos\gamma & -1  \\ -1 & \cos\gamma \end{pmatrix} \\ & = \cos \beta \cdot \left (-\cos \beta-\cos\gamma\cdot \cos\alpha\right )-\cos \alpha \cdot \left (\cos\gamma\cdot \cos\beta-(-1)\cdot \cos\alpha\right )-\left (\cos^2 \gamma -(-1)^2\right ) \\ & =-\cos^2 \beta-\cos\gamma\cdot \cos\alpha\cdot \cos \beta-\cos\alpha\cdot \cos\gamma\cdot \cos\beta- \cos^2\alpha-\cos^2 \gamma +1 \\ & =1-2\cdot \cos\alpha\cdot \cos\beta\cdot \cos\gamma - \cos^2\alpha-\cos^2 \beta-\cos^2 \gamma \end{align*}

Do we use here the Law of cosines?
\begin{align*}&c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cdot \cos \gamma \Rightarrow  \cos \gamma=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} \\ &b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cdot \cos \beta \Rightarrow \cos \beta=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac} \\ &a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cdot \cos \alpha \Rightarrow \cos\alpha=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\end{align*}

Or how could we continue?

Comment: $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$.

Comment: So, you mean to calculate $\cos \gamma=\cos (\pi -\alpha-\beta)=-\cos (\alpha+\beta )$ ?  @JohnB

Comment: See https://www.tutel.me/c/mathematics/questions/1419652/prove+that+in+triangle+abccos2acos2bcos2cgeqfrac34

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: what is the point in citing some site which gathers answers from MSE, instead of linking a MSE thread directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a point $P$ has trilinear coordinates $[\cos B,\cos A,-1]$ it lies on the height from vertex $C$, since the circumcenter and the orthocenter are isogonal conjugates and the distances of the circumcenter from the $BC$ and $AC$ sides are exactly given by $R\cos A$ and $R\cos B$. The claim turns out to be equivalent to the collinearity of three points at infinity, or, by duality, to the concurrency of the heights of a triangle. In a simpler way,

$$ \begin{pmatrix}c & b & a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos B & \cos A & -1 \\ \cos C & -1 & \cos A \\ -1 & \cos C & \cos B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
hence the determinant of the given matrix is trivially zero.

Comment: I haven;t really understood that idea. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar: if for some vector $v\neq 0$ we have $Mv=0$ then $M$ is not invertible, hence its determinant is zero. The same idea here, but applied to the transpose of $M$ (whose determinant equals $\det M$).

Comment: The key relations $c \cos B + b \cos C=a$ and so on are pretty evident once you draw a diagram including the triangle and its heights.

Comment: Why does $c \cos B + b \cos C=a$ hold?

Comment: @MaryStar: draw it! If $H_A$ is the foot of the height from $A$, $$ a=BC=BH_A+H_A C = c \cos B + b\cos C.$$

Comment: Ah I understand these relations! But why did you multiply the vector from the left at the matrix? Can we not write the system that we get in the form $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \beta & \cos\alpha & -1 \\ \cos \gamma & -1 & \cos\alpha \\ -1 & \cos\beta & \cos \gamma\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
 ?

Comment: The sides of a triangle must be positiv so the vector is non-zero and so we conclude that the determinant of the matrix must be zero, right?

Comment: @MaryStar: the side lengths of a triangle are positive by definition, and in any case you just need that *some* number among $a,b,c$ differs from zero.

Comment: Shouldn't every number of the a,b,c must be greater than 0, since they are the length of a side of a triangle?

Comment: $(a,b,c)$ is a non-zero vector iff *some* of its entries are non-zero. You do not need that each entry is positive, but that is true, in any case. The identity you wrote does not hold, in general. $(c,b,a)$ is only a *left* eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue, and $v^T M \neq M v$.

Comment: So, is the matrix form of the system that I wrote wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar:no, the matrix is correct and $(c,b,a)$ is a *left* eigenvector of such a matrix.

Comment: Ah ok! I see!! Thank you so much for your help!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

the product of the three cosines is given by $$-\frac{\left(a^2-b^2-c^2\right)
   \left(a^2+b^2-c^2\right) \left(a^2-b^2+c^2\right)}{2
   a^2 b^2 c^2}$$
for your second sum we get
$$2 \left(\frac{\left(a^2+b^2-c^2\right)^2}{4 a^2
   b^2}+\frac{\left(a^2-b^2+c^2\right)^2}{4 b^2
   c^2}+\frac{\left(-a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^2}{4 b^2
   c^2}\right)=\frac{2 a^6-4 a^4 b^2+a^4 c^2+2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2
   c^2+b^4 c^2-2 b^2 c^4+c^6}{2 a^2 b^2 c^2}$$you must only multiply out the first sum

Comment: "*M.I.A.E.*" - *M*ost *I*nefficient *A*pproach *E*ver.

Comment: ok it is inefficient but this  gives a possible way to solve this!

Comment: You can simply ignore the trilinear coordinates part and read *since $\text{Ker}\,M^t$ is non trivial, $\det M=0$*.

Comment: yes ok, we have not a war here, but we all can help the questioners